# ELF Dissasembly - what ".init .text .plt" means?

Tags: assembly, elf

I'm watching my ELF disassembly and some lines are like this:

```
.text:000105e0 00 b0 a0 e3  mov fp, #0
.text:000105e8 04 10 9d e4  pop {r1}; (ldr r1, [sp], #4)
```

others like this:

```
.plt:00010568 00 c6 8f e2    add    ip, pc, #0, 12
.plt:0001056c 10 ca 8c e2    add    ip, ip, #16, 20 ; 0x10000
```

and others like:

```
.init:00010544 08 40 2d e9   push   {r3, lr}
```

What does the **.text, .plt and .init** parts of the disassembly lines means?

Comment: They're section names and they give a clue what the purpose of the code you're disassembling is for, including if it's actually supposed to be code and not data.

Comment: Thanks, would you consider making your comment an answer?

Comment: They are program sections, please [see this](https://greek0.net/elf.html). BTW I had some idea (from assembler experience in general). I just googled **elf plt** and there it was.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

.init, .text and .plt are linker sections.

1. **.init** contains startup code
2. **.text** contains program code
3. **.plt** is used when calling functions whose addresses can not be known at linking time (but will be resolved by dynamic linker at run time)

There are moreover lots of other possible sections containing code, data or constants.